# Showing Convergence in Uniform implies convergence L-2 metric

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, uniform-convergence

Show that if $f_n$ converges to f in uniform metric then $f_n$ converges to f in $L^2$ metric.

Attempt at solution:

If $f_n$ converges to $f$ in uniform metric then  $\sup_{x \in I}|f_n(x)-f(x)| \to 0$), then 
$$\|f_n-f\|_2=\int_a^b |f_n(x)-f(x)|^2\,dx \leq \int_a^b sup (|f_n(x)-f(x)|)^2\,dx\ \leq \ (b-a) sup (|f_n(x)-f(x)|)^2\,dx\ $$  and we know this last equality tends to 0, so we have $L^2$ convergence.  I'm not sure if my proof is entirely correct however.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The proof is completely correct. (The '$dx$' must be removed in the last step.)

Comment: Oh yes, thanks.